# Pandas get the number of date - periods based on frequency between two datetimes/dates

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, frequency

I have two columns with dates and I am wondering if there is a concise way of getting the number of "Periods" (i.e. 'D', 'W', 'M', 'Q','Y') between the two of them without building a whole lot of custom mappings.

```
    first_transaction   order_date
0   2014-06-26  2014-06-29
1   2014-02-23  2015-01-09
2   2014-02-23  2014-02-23
3   2016-03-22  2016-03-22
4   2016-03-22  2017-10-20
```

I.e. for frequency 'Q' id like to get

```
    first_transaction   order_date  res
0   2014-06-26  2014-06-29  0
1   2014-02-23  2015-01-09  4
2   2014-02-23  2014-04-23  1
3   2016-03-22  2016-08-22  2
4   2016-03-22  2017-10-20  7
```

Comment: you can use `np.timedelta` to map your values into your frequencies using metadata arguments, eg `(df['order_date'] - df['first_transaction']) / np.timedelta64(3,'M')`

Comment: @Datanovice To get whole units you may use ceil `np.ceil(((df['second'] - df['first']) / np.timedelta64(3,'M')))`

Comment: @Datanovice I don't think that this will produce the results that I am looking for as it possible for two dates to be 3 months + 2 days apart and be in Q1 and Q3 of a year.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the difference between the two dates (once you've converted to date), and figure out the relevant unit arithmetically.

```
from math import ceil
import datetime
df = df.applymap(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%y'))
df.apply(lambda y: ceil(((y['order_date'].year - y['first_transaction'].year)*12 + (y['order_date'].month - y['first_transaction'].month))/3), axis = 1)
```

Comment: I am well aware :) but thats super annoying ^^

Comment: Pandas Timestamp object has a quarter attribute. You could follow a similar approach to the above and get only the annualized quarter difference.

Comment: that means coding up the entire logic, I was wondering if there is something more native